# Generate .bat file for a spring project using maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I have done project with spring and maven in eclipse. Now I want to run the application without eclipse means I want to run java.class file from .bat file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a .bat file, then you probably need to create a shaded jar containing all of your dependencies (an "Über Jar"). This is done with the [mvn shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) by adding something like this to your pom.xml:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer
              implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.foo.bar.Main</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then, in your .bat file, you can execute your Java application using

```
java -jar myJarFile.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a `.bat` file for running your application you can use [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which is exactly for such purposes. It can create `.bat` as well as `.sh` scripts to run your application. Furthermore you can pack the resulting files into a zip archive which contains your application with the `scripts` the needed libs as well as configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

With the Maven goal `package` you get a runnable archive file. The way you run that file depends on the project. It could be a simple `.jar` file you can run with the JVM, it could be a `.war` file you have to deploy to a application server or even something entirely else. But `mvn clean package` would definitely be the first step to go.

Comment: If I create .war file and deploy the .war file in application server then how can I run the app. as far as I understand about .war file, the application could be called by http request. In my code I don't use any servlet at all then how can I run my app if I deploy in application server as .war file?

Comment: I think you'd have to create a servlet for that. Every web application needs some kind of entry point. You don't just run it using a main method. How it's done really depends on the framework you are using.

Comment: @niren I am a bit confused because in the comment above you talk about a .war file for an application server; whereas in the OP you ask about launching your application with a .bat file. This seems contradictory.

Comment: am looking for both way to deploy my application, I should have ask different question for this but since @stonedsquirrel discussed about .war I asked this question.